# Trim a file using tail in linux

Tags: linux

How do I reduce the size of a file using tail?

I just need the last 1000 lines of the file. I need the trimmed file name to remain the same.

Comment: In the future, you might be better served checking the man pages. It would likely be quicker. http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tail

Answer (score 10):

```
tail -1000 file.txt
```

To make a new file

```
tail -1000 file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Also, `tail -1000 file.txt > newfile && mv newfile file.txt`

Comment: Just a warning, the above will NOT preserve the mode or ownership of 'file.txt', which can be quite disasterous for log files with special permissions.  Instead, since you're using a intermediate file anyway, use 'cp' with 'rm': ``tail -1000 file.txt > tmpfile.txt && cp tmpfile.txt file.txt && rm tmpfile.txt`` ... Modes and ownership are preserved without any issues.